# Sql Update command VB.Net With Date

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

I have an SQL update command that I can't get to work. i want it to update the fields where the date is equal to the current date. It works for my INSERT and SELECT statements. But I get a missing operator error when using it for my Delete statement below.

```
     Cmd.Connection = conn
     Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_Expenditure SET E_Stock =" & NewEStock & "," & "E_Total =" & ETotal & "WHERE [E_Date] = #" & thisMonth & "/" & Day & "/" & thisYear & "#;"
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Ive tried searching this site as well as others and can't seem to find an answer.

This is my error

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '95WHERE [E_Date] = #4/1/2015#'.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The error message contains the answer. 95WHERE Is not a valid keyword.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_Expenditure SET E_Stock = @Stock, E_Total = @Total WHERE [E_Date] = @Date;", conn)

    'Guessing at column types here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stock", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewEStock
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Decimal, 8, 2).Value = ETotal
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = New DateTime(thisYear, thisMonth, Day)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

This fixes a **HUGE** security issue in the code, it has a performance benefit in allowing Sql Server to cache your query plan, and it solves your problem in that is makes it *much* easier to spot silly syntax mistakes like the missing space in front of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Decimal, 8, 2).Value = @ETotal` should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Decimal, 8, 2).Value = ETotal`.